# Accessing a Liferay portal with different hosts

Tags: url, liferay, portal

What is the difference between accessing a Liferay portal with 
`http://portal.name.com` for example, and `http://name.com`?

I noticed that when I use `portal.name.com`, an additional `/web/guest` is added to the URL. But when accessing the portal using `name.com`, the URL stays fixed.

Comment: You can publish portal under any URL. There's no difference.

Comment: I noticed that when I use http://portal.name.com , an additional /web/guest is added to the URL. But when accessing the portal using  http://name.com, the URL stays fixed.

Comment: You should always integrate such clarifying information into your question - like I did now for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're configuring an explicit virtual host name for a site, Liferay can find out what site you're referring to (that's the `guest` part of the URL) and omit it. `web` points to the public pages of a site - and always needs to be followed by a site name.

You can revert that behaviour by setting the site name for the guest URL to `portal.name.com`, which would cause the `/web/guest` part to appear on `name.com`.